# Magento 1.7 CatalogSearch with Sphinx

Tags: magento, sphinx

I’m trying to connect my Sphinx with Magento 1.7. I could this easily with 1.5 using this [document](http://tonyhb.co.uk/2012/05/using-sphinx-within-magento-plus-optimising-search-result-rankings-weights-and-relevancy/), but as Magento core code changed since 1.5, i cannot edit the same source files of magento, it won’t work obviosuly. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

I have empty classes for the files which need to be changed and i've made searches for these methods to be modified, but they are not present anymore.

Cheers,
Zsolt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files to edit:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Engine.php
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Helper/Data.php
```